# expectation of Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, poisson-process

Let $T_i$ (i = 0, 1, 2,...) be the arrival times of a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. Let
$$ N = inf\{k > 1:T_k - T_{k-1} > T_1\}$$ Find E(N).

I understand that the solution, which is first to calculate P(N $\geq$ n) = $\frac{1}{n-1}$ and then do the summation. But I am wondering why cannot I regard N as a Geometric distribution with success probability $p = P(T_k - T_{k-1} > T_1)$ and then E(N) = $\frac{1}{p}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you gone through the calculation to see if you get the right answer?

Comment: Also, a geometric random variable is supported on $\mathbb{N}$ (or sometimes even $\mathbb{W}$), but our random variable $N$ is supported on $\{2,3, \ldots \}$ and has pmf $$p_N(n)=(1/2)^{n-1}$$ Here we have independent trials because the interarrival times of a poisson process are independent.  I'm getting $\mu_N = 3$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Yes, I have gone through the calculation. The correct answer should be  infinity.

Comment: How are you getting that $P(N \geq n)$ equals $\frac{1}{n-1}$? Have you used the fact that the pdf for the interarrival times are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$? An infinite expectation here doesn't seem right.